# Migrar proyecto Django de un PC a otro

Tags: django

Hola ante todo saludos y gracias por su interés, tengo el siguiente problema; he desarrollado un proyecto de django básico pero quiero pasarlo de mi pc a otro pc nuevo que he comprado y no se si hacer lo mismo que cuando instalé y copiar el proyecto o lleve un tratamiento especial. Si alguien me da alguna referencia se agradece. Estoy usando una base de datos de WAMP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para pasar tu proyecto de una Pc a otra, debes primero analizar si te interesa tambien llevar la base de datos actual o no.
En el caso de no serlo es facil.

- Instala django en tu nuevo Pc
- Instala las librerias necesarias que tengas o requieran tu proyecto
  como ocr, opepyxl, xhtml2pdf ...etc...

Para mayor facilitad de todo lo que tienes instalado o las librerias necesarias debes usar el comando :

```
pip freeze
```

Dicho comando te mostrra el listado completo de todas tus librerias que usa tu proyecto django y sus respectivas versiones con esa lista es recomendable crear un archivo llamado :

```
requirements.txt
```

este por lo general esta a la altura de la raiz de tu proyecto, con esta lista es mas facil migrar o mover tus proyectos de un lugar a otro incluso para produccion,. ejemplo de listado(requirements.txt):

```
docutils==0.11
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.19
Pygments==1.6
Sphinx==1.2.2
```

una vez copiado el proyecto he instalado django en tu nueva pc abres una terminal o consola de comandos sea windows o linux, y para instalar las librerias seria algo asi:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Para mayor detalle de esta lista te recomiendo revisar esto:
[Pip Freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)
ya con eso deberias crear tu superuser, hacer el makemigrations, migrate y runserver. basicamente eso seria todo...espero te pueda guiar y ayudar...suerte !!

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` en una sola linea

Comment: gracias no me lo sabia.. @JackNavaRow

Comment: Hola estuve desconectado unos días por trabajo gracias por su respuesta me ha servido de mucho saludos